# Content in Table cell of iOS 8 is not display

Tags: objective-c, ios8, tablecell

Everything works well in iOS 9.
But in iOS 8, the content is not displayed, only imageview is showed.

What i did is that I create a view and add label and UIImage to that view. Then that view is added to contentView of table Cell

**create View**

```
- (UIView *)getHeaderView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, HEADER_SECTION_HEIGHT)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[[RNThemeManager sharedManager] colorWithHexString:[_themeComponent valueForKey:@"Layer1Color"]]];

    UILabel *taskName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, SECTION_BREAK+3.0, view.frame.size.width-23.0, 20)];
    [taskName setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[[_themeComponent valueForKey:@"RegularFontSize"] intValue]]];
    [taskName setText:combinedTask.taskDescription];
    [taskName setTextColor: [[RNThemeManager sharedManager] colorWithHexString:[_themeComponent valueForKey:@"textPrimary"]]];
    [view addSubview:taskName];

UIImageView *addressView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, SECTION_BREAK+28.0, 20, 20)];
    addressView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", @"Attr_Pin"]];
    [view addSubview:addressView];

    UILabel *address = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35.0, SECTION_BREAK+23.0, view.frame.size.width-35.0, 30)];
    [address setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[[_themeComponent valueForKey:@"SmallFontSize"] intValue]]];
    address.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    address.numberOfLines = 0;

    [address setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", unit]];
    [address setTextColor: [[RNThemeManager sharedManager] colorWithHexString:[_themeComponent valueForKey:@"textPrimary"]]];
    [view addSubview:address];
    return view;
}
```

**Add view to table cell**

```
UIView *header= [self getHeaderView:tableView viewForHeaderInSection:section];
cell.taskIdLabel.hidden = YES;

[cell.contentView addSubview:header];
```

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because iOS 9 Apple handle good autolayout than before.
Let add [cell layoutIfNeeded] before return cell. 
Update 
I have same problem before. Here is block of code that i use to solved my problem.

```
- (void) sizeHeaderToFit {

    //call in viewLayoutSubView
    UIView *myHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;

    [myHeaderView setNeedsLayout];
    [myHeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
    CGFloat height = [myHeaderView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    myHeaderView.frame = ({
        CGRect headerFrame = myHeaderView.frame;
        headerFrame.size.height = height;
        headerFrame;
    });

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myHeaderView;
}
```

call it at viewDidLayoutSubView. Hope it helps bạn :))

Comment: I tried [cell.contentView setNeedsDisplay];
        [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded]; and also [cell setNeedsDisplay];
        [cell layoutIfNeeded]; yesterday, but no luck.

Comment: The weird thing here is uiimage is displayed but others aren't